# How to pattern match for a True/False within a function in Haskell?

Tags: if-statement, haskell, error-handling, functional-programming, switch-statement

I am trying to handle file errors manually so I can print my own message and currently I have this code:

```hs
handleFileError :: FileError -> IO a
handleFileError (FileError errorKind) = do
  case errorKind of
    NotFound -> undefined
    NoPermission -> undefined
    IsDirectory -> undefined

fileRead :: String -> IO String
fileRead file = do
  pathExists <- doesPathExist file
  notDirectory <- doesFileExist file

  -- These two must be handled before `System.Directory.getPermissions` is called
  -- or else it will error.

  permissions <- getPermissions file
  let hasReadPermissions = readable permissions

  if hasReadPermissions then undefined -- This is the success case
  else handleFileError $ FileError NoPermissions
```

I would like to check if any of the 3 booleans (pathExists, notDirectory, and hasReadPermissions) are false, and then act accordingly. I tried to implement this using a case with `False`, however this just always runs the first branch.

Comment: What exactly have you tried with a `case`?

Comment: Can't you just do `if not (pathExists && notDirectory && hasReadPermissions) then failureCase else successCase`?

Comment: I can't see anything really wrong with your code. `case` should also work, but if you want to use an `if` as shown above, that's OK.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I did something like `case False of` and then matched `pathExists` on one, `notDirectory` on another etc - And I got warnings saying that the other patterns were redundant, and it would always match the first, even if it were true

Comment: @Noughtmare The issue is there is a different action for each, as the function `handleFileError` takes a type `FileError ErrorKind`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to use `MultiWayIf`:

```
do
  pathExists <- doesPathExist file
  notDirectory <- doesFileExist file
  permissions <- unsafeInterleaveIO (getPermissions file)
  if
    | not pathExists -> -- ...
    | not notDirectory -> -- ...
    | not permissions -> -- ...
    | otherwise -> -- ...
```

If you're allergic to extensions, the old-fashioned way to get this feature is using guards, as in:

```
  case () of
    _ | not pathExists -> -- ...
      | not notDirectory -> -- ...
      | not permissions -> -- ...
      | otherwise -> -- ...
```

But I recommend neither of these. Instead, just do something with the file, and catch the exception; otherwise there are race conditions with the file system changing out from under you between the check and the file use. Like this:

```
fileRead :: String -> IO String
fileRead = catch (undefined {- success case -}) $ \e -> if
  | isDoesNotExistError e -> -- ...
  | isPermissionError e -> -- ...
  | otherwise -> throw e
```

Comment: Using `unsafeInterleaveIO` sound like a bad idea to me. It is very easy to mess up the evaluation order. It should really only be used by experts who know what they are doing and even they make mistakes with it sometimes.

Comment: @Noughtmare Maybe. Perhaps a comment in the code would be warranted here. But the reasoning needed to see that this is okay here is very local and contained -- the ease of reading the resulting code is well worth it in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this - I didnt realise that it was possible to nest `if` statements in a way that functions like else-if in other languages:

```hs
if not (pathExists) then handleFileError $ FileError NotFound
  else if not (notDirectory) then handleFileError $ FileError IsDirectory
  else do
    permissions <- getPermissions file
    let hasReadPermissions = readable permissions

    if hasReadPermissions then undefined -- success
    else handleFileERror $ FileError NoPermissions
```

Comment: This is awkward though. Consider using [`when`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:when) instead, it should work mostly the same in this example but doesn't require an `else` branch.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Doesn't the OP actually require the `else` branch?

Comment: I'd say you should follow Daniel Wagner's solution. It is bad practice to check for "file exists" before doing file operation, many bugs were caused by such race in the file system.